# Spring synchronization issue

Tags: java, spring, synchronization

I know that question about reusing prototype beans was asked many times, but my question means more than this.

**What is the problem:**

I start asynchronous tasks in handler (prototype bean) in for-lookup. but I can't start the next asynchronous task before the previous reach some milestone. So I have to proceed for-loop only after the previous task invokes a special method.

**What the questions:**

1. *How to wait in for-loop before some method call in another bean?*
2. *Can I invoke proceedLookUp() method of current prototype bean from another beans?*

---

```
@Service(value = "Request.Start")
@Scope("prototype")
public static class Start {

  public Start() {}

  private Object lock;

  @Transactional
  public void handler(Request request, Response response) {

    for (int i = 0; i < request.getAmount(); i++) {
      Utils.asyncProcessStart(); //Can't start the next async process before the previous rich some defined milestone
      lock.wait();
    }
  }

  public void proceedLookUp() {
    lock.notify();
  }
}

@Service
public void AsynchronousTask {

  public void asyncAction() [
    //Needed logic, before start the next async task
    getStartHandler().proceedLookUp();
  }

  public void getStartHandler() {
    //HOW TO REWRITE NEEDED PROTOTYPE BEAN
  } 
}
```

**ADDITION:**

***What is the problem***: I use Activiti framework, which imply some restrictions. I should store some variables to a process (thread) context. I CAN write variables to a global context, BUT CAN'T write to a local process (thread) context before the process (thread) has been started.

> what you expect to happen, say if request.getAmount() returns 2?

I should start two asynchronous processes in two different threads. Each process have **the same set of variables**. I must **write appropriate variables to the local context of each process (thread)**. But, I **CAN'T** do it **before the process (thread) is started** (due to the specific of Activiti framework).

For example, each process (thread) should write "id" property to his own local context. I have *List ids* in *handler* method

So, I should do the next sequence of actions:

1. Write ids.get(0) as "id"-property to GLOBAL context
2. Start the first process
3. Hang on the for-loop
4. [Inside the first process] write "id" property from global to local context (it is possible inside the first process)
5. Notify appropriate Start bean that it can continue the for-loop
6. Write ids.get(1) as "id"-property to GLOBAL context
7. Start the second process
8. Hang on the for-loop
9. [Inside the second process] write "id" property from global to local context (it is possible inside the second process)
10. Notify appropriate Start bean that it can continue the for-loop

> Why can't you just call it synchronously?

As you have already understood, there is no guarantee that the first process (thread) write the "id"-property to it local context, before it has been overriden by for-loop for the second process (thread).

Comment: Please, tell why you can't answer my question: is it too complex, I provided unsufficient amount of code or something else. There are 68 reviews and any comment!

Comment: Can you draw a simple sequence diagram of what you expect to happen, say if request.getAmount() returns 2? Your handler method seems to be creating a new thread and running the asyncAction() method but then blocking. Why can't you just call it synchronously?

Comment: Answers to your question in ADDITION section of my question. If something not clear for you, please, ask me again

Comment: Thanks for the addition. One follow up - when you refer to your "global context", what object (class) is that?

Comment: It is _RuntimeService_ class of Activiti framework, _setVariable_ method. This class also has _setVariableLocal_, but it suggest executionId (id of new process) as a parameter (wich is accessible only after new asynchronous process is started).

Comment: I haven't worked with Activiti. But I'm wondering if inside your new threads you have a reference to the RuntimeService instance (or can look it up)? It seems like the crux of the problem is that you want to send some information (state) from a parent thread to some child threads. If both the parent thread and child threads have access to the Global state context via the RuntimeService class, this should be solvable.

Comment: The point is that both parent and child thread have access two _RuntimeService_, but to set variables to child-local context I should know child's id. But I can't know child's id before I start it.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your needs, the pseudo-code doesn't help (it is not sufficient), why do you need to start one thread per amount? For performance?

Comment: Because I use Activiti framework: it is Bussiness Process Modeling framework. As you understand, this framework dessigned to modeling the whole process of my application. It is essential, that one process may call another process (it is not obligatiry). So it is logical that two almost independent processes should perform in different threads.

Comment: Have you tested my suggestion? Does it work for you?

Comment: Firstly thank you for your reply. Sory, have no time to test it yet. But I'm going to test it today or tomorrow ,and necessarily accept it if it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's my suggestion: create a singleton object that you can share between your threads to pass information (state). The singleton uses a [semaphore](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/semaphores.html) to coordinate between your threads. You can use this approach to pass the new thread's identity back to your Service class. Here's a simple example that shows what I'm proposing.

The test class:

public class TestSemaphore {

```
    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {

        ThreadCoordinator tc = ThreadCoordinator.getInstance();

        for( int i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) {
            MyThread r = new MyThread();
            r.run();

            // This will block until the Thread has called release (after setting its identity on the ThreadCoordinator)    
            tc.acquire();
            String newThreadIdentity = tc.getIdentity();
            System.out.println( "Received the new thread's identity:         " + newThreadIdentity );

            // This will allow the next Thread to acquire the semaphore
            tc.release();
        }
    }


    class MyThread extends Thread {

        public void run() {
            String identity = Integer.toString( (int)(Math.random() * 10000) );
            System.out.println( "Running a new thread with identity:         " + identity );

            // Get a reference to the singleton
            ThreadCoordinator tc = ThreadCoordinator.getInstance();
            try {
                tc.acquire();
                tc.setIdentity( identity );
                System.out.println( "Notified the ThreadCoordinator from thread: " + identity );
                tc.release();
            } catch( InterruptedException e ) {
                System.out.println( "Caught an interrupted exception: " + e );
            }

        }

    }
}
```

The ThreadCoordinator (semaphore) class:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class ThreadCoordinator {

        private static ThreadCoordinator tc = new ThreadCoordinator();
        private static Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore( 1, true );      
        private static String identity;

        // singleton get instance
        public static ThreadCoordinator getInstance() {
            return ThreadCoordinator.tc;
        }

        public void setIdentity( String identity ) throws InterruptedException {
            ThreadCoordinator.identity = identity;
        }


        public String getIdentity() throws InterruptedException {
            String identity = ThreadCoordinator.identity;
            ThreadCoordinator.identity = null;
            return identity;
        }

        public void acquire() throws InterruptedException {
            ThreadCoordinator.semaphore.acquire();
        }

        public void release() {
            ThreadCoordinator.semaphore.release();
        }

 }
```